# Reading text file in java using scanner

Tags: java, file, text, java.util.scanner

I am a beginner. Reading from text file in Java using a scanner. This code just to read the first 3 tokens isn't working:

```
try{
Scanner scFile = new Scanner (new File ("readhere.txt")).useDelimiter("#");
String first = scFile.next();
String second = scFile.next();
int third = scFile.nextInt(); // error here. Why cant I store the integer?
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

I am trying to read just the first 3 tokens:

```
Andrew#Smith#21
John#Morris#55
```

the problem occurs when reading 21. java.util.InputMismatchException

Comment: did you try and check what the type of the value that the `Scanner ` read? If not int, can you see what could it be?

Comment: I tried reading the next token as scFile.next() and storing it as a string. The scanner moved on to the next line and printed:                                               21                                                                                                                        John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scanner is including the carriage return character(s) as part of the next readable token which produces an invalid integer. You could do

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("readhere.txt")).useDelimiter("#|\r\n");
```

Comment: This worked, still need to learn how though. Any other workaround?